# Order color based on Hue, Saturation, Value in R

Tags: r, colors, color-theory

This question is combination of R and color-theory

I am trying to order color based on Hue (h), then Saturation (s), and finally Value (v)

Here are the painted colors and dataframe from code at end of this post

#### Painted

[image]

#### Dataframe

```
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
h 0.6229508 0.2767296 0.1323283 0.9790476 0.9093567
s 0.6421053 0.5145631 0.7928287 0.9510870 0.5480769
v 0.3725490 0.8078431 0.9843137 0.7215686 0.4078431
```

Do I find the color with lowest h value, keep that as 1st position, out of remaining 4 colors, then find the color with lowest hue, and so forth.

Then how would one sort by saturation, then value.

Note, I'm not asking for code, but rather the logic for doing this.

Any guidance is appreciated.

#### Code

```
library(RanglaPunjab)

# Paint the colors
PaintPalette("Teej")

# Store the hex values
mycolors <- RanglaPunjab("Teej")

# Print hex values
mycolors

# Convert Hex to RGB
RGBcol <- col2rgb(mycolors)

# Print RGB values
RGBcol

# Convert RGB to HSV
HSVcol <- rgb2hsv(RGBcol)

# Print dataframe
HSVcol
```

Comment: You'll want to transpose your data. Right now, each column is an observation (i.e. a color). You want data where each row is an observation. From there, you can use `order` to sort your data pretty easily.

Comment: After you've transposed the data, you can also use `arrange` from `dplyr` to easily sort by each of the columns and allow for readability. So the code would end up looking like `HSVcol_transposed %>% arrange(h)` for sorting by hue

Comment: So far I understand (1) Transpose (2) Arrange to sort