# dplyr Arrange does not work

Tags: r, dplyr

Reference question, [Order color based on Hue, Saturation, Value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045459/order-color-based-on-hue-saturation-value-in-r)

I have the following dataframe that I wish to sort based on h, then s, and finally v

```
> library(dplyr)
> tHSVcol
             h         s         v
[1,] 0.6229508 0.6421053 0.3725490
[2,] 0.2767296 0.5145631 0.8078431
[3,] 0.1323283 0.7928287 0.9843137
[4,] 0.9790476 0.9510870 0.7215686
[5,] 0.9093567 0.5480769 0.4078431
```

When I execute `tHSVcol  %>%  arrange(desc(h))`, I get

> `Error in UseMethod("arrange_") :    no applicable method for
>   'arrange_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double',
>   'numeric')"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a matrix.  Convert to data.frame and it should work. As the error explains, there is no method to deal with `matrix` class  `tHSVcol %>% as.data.frame %>% arrange(desc(h))`

Comment: Thanks, will research matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your matrix is called `m`, you can do:

```
m[order(m[,"h"], decreasing = T), ]

#             h         s         v
#[1,] 0.9790476 0.9510870 0.7215686
#[2,] 0.9093567 0.5480769 0.4078431
#[3,] 0.6229508 0.6421053 0.3725490
#[4,] 0.2767296 0.5145631 0.8078431
#[5,] 0.1323283 0.7928287 0.9843137
```