# Find Ordered Position in Matrix

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

For reference, [Order color based on Hue, Saturation, Value in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045459/order-color-based-on-hue-saturation-value-in-r)

I understand `sort` will return sorted dataframe and `order` will return the position of an element if it was ordered.

What is similar type of function for matrices.

I can sort a matrix, but I wish to know the position of an element if it is sorted

```
> tHSVcol
             h         s         v
[1,] 0.6229508 0.6421053 0.3725490
[2,] 0.2767296 0.5145631 0.8078431
[3,] 0.1323283 0.7928287 0.9843137
[4,] 0.9790476 0.9510870 0.7215686
[5,] 0.9093567 0.5480769 0.4078431

> tHSVcol[order(tHSVcol[,1])]
[1] 0.1323283 0.2767296 0.6229508 0.9093567 0.9790476
```

Function I am looking for should return. Please advise

```
> ???
[1] 3 2 1 5 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of `match()` and `sort()` will get what you want:

```
mat <- matrix(9:1, 3,3, byrow = TRUE)

match(sort(mat[,1]), mat[,1])
3 2 1
```

Answer (score 3):

One option would be `rank`

```
rank(tHSVcol[,1])
#[1] 3 2 1 5 4
```

#### data

```
tHSVcol <- structure(c(0.6229508, 0.2767296, 0.1323283, 0.9790476, 0.9093567, 
0.6421053, 0.5145631, 0.7928287, 0.951087, 0.5480769, 0.372549, 
0.8078431, 0.9843137, 0.7215686, 0.4078431), .Dim = c(5L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
   NULL, c("h", "s", "v")))
```